# Not able installing mini-css-extract plugin into my project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, ckeditor5

I'm trying install npm install --save \ mini-css-extract-plugin \  css-loader but i'm getting this error in my webpack,can someone help me out with whats the issue here? is it webpack ver or the `node_modules`?

`package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
    }
```

Error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document@24.0.0
npm ERR! Found: webpack@4.46.0
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^4.43.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^5.0.0" from mini-css-extract-plugin@2.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin
npm ERR!   mini-css-extract-plugin@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

UPDATE:
`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const { bundler, styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin' );
const TerserPlugin = require( 'terser-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    performance: { hints: false },

    entry: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'ckeditor.js' ),

    output: {
        // The name under which the editor will be exported.
        library: 'DecoupledEditor',

        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'build' ),
        filename: 'ckeditor.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default'
    },

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin( {
                sourceMap: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        // Preserve CKEditor 5 license comments.
                        comments: /^!/
                    }
                },
                extractComments: false
            } )
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
            // UI language. Language codes follow the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 format.
            // When changing the built-in language, remember to also change it in the editor's configuration (src/ckeditor.js).
            language: 'en',
            additionalLanguages: 'all'
        } ),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin( {
            banner: bundler.getLicenseBanner(),
            raw: true
        } )
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                            attributes: {
                                'data-cke': true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiniCssExtractPlugin requires [webpack 5](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/) to work.

Starting from [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0) minimum supported webpack version is 5.0.0

As an option, you can try to use MiniCssExtractPlugin [version 1.6.2](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/releases/tag/v1.6.2).
Also consider upgrading to webpack5, but [raw-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/) plugin is deprecated as well as [terser-webpack-plugin](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/#getting-started)